# trying to update database flag if condition user id exist in another table using cronjob

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I am trying to update " user table starred flag to 1 " if id of **users** table exist in **user_pages**,

Here are both table structures

**1- users table**

```
| id | starred |
| 1  |    0    |
```

**2- user_pages table**

```
| uid |
| 2   |
| 5   |
| 1   |
```

I am trying to do it with this cron command :

```
$query="update users up join
users u
on up.id = u.id
set up.starred = (case when u.id = uid then 1 else 0 end)";
mysql_query($query);
```

**Expected Results**

```
| id | starred |
| 1  |    1    |
```

Please help me out to update a flag if id exist in another table

**Note:**:

Id is = **id** in users table

Id is = **uid** in user_pages table

Comment: Are you trying to unset `starred` if it's not present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update user u join user_pages up on u.id = up.uid
set u.starred = 1 where u.id in (select uid from user_pages);
```

Comment: Working for me now !!! after little correction > 

update users u join user_pages up on u.id = up.uid
set u.starred = 1 where u.id in (select uid from user_pages);

Comment: The JOIN and WHERE are redundant

Answer (score 0):

Here's one simple way:

```
UPDATE users u
  JOIN user_pages up ON up.uid = u.id
   SET u.starred = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 UPDATE users a 
 JOIN user_pages  b ON a.id = b.uid
 SET a.starred = 1 where a.id = 1 //or your update id
```

users.starred is updated only, if uid exists in uses_pags table